# Excel: Select MIN value in column, while applying IF to another column

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a table called Data, that looks like this:

```
Region Age
West   21
East   18
East   21
West   26
East   27
```

I want to be able to select the minimum and maximum age for each region. The function below should pick the minimum age from the region "West":

```
=MIN(IF(Data[Region]:Data[Region]="West";Data[Age]:Data[Age]))
```

Instead it only selects the minimum age from the current line. How to modify it to work with whole column data?

Comment: I would use a pivot table for this exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just responded to a similar thread recently but it did not reference structured tables. If you are operating under Excel 2010 or higher, then the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) would make a quick formula.

[image: AGGREGATE MINIF and MAXIF]

The standard formulas in D2:D3 are,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, Data[Age]/(Data[Region]=D$1), 1)
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, Data[Age]/(Data[Region]=D$1), 1)
```

Fill right as necessary.

The added bonus to this style of pseudo-MAXIF/MINIF formula is that you are actually using the LARGE or SMALL sub-function of AGGREGATE. By increasing the *k* parameter (the *1* on the end) you can receive the second, third, etc. value.

¹<sub>AGGREGATE was introduced with Excel 2010. If you have a previous version, post a comment and another solution may be possible.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The formula itself was ok, but I needed to enter it as an array formula (pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when entering it instead of simple ENTER)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost close to it expect that you need to mention that it as an `Array Formula`

After you key in the formula, instead of Pressing Enter Key, Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter and its converted to array formula and computes the result in Single Cell.

You would notice that the Formula would be changed to `{=MIN(IF(Data[Region]:Data[Region]="West",Data[Age]:Data[Age]))}`